# Erro Chrome bot - ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Tenho uma aplicação em python que executa algumas tarefas repetitivas por mim abrindo o chrome e utilizando-o como bot (não posso estar disponibilizando o código da mesma pois trabalho com contrato de sigilo), mas ao executar ela aparecem esses erros e algumas vezes o programa não executa de forma correta.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58590/devtools/browser/46dd5f63-bae8-4996-85d9-92027184f6ee
[6892:7320:1009/142755.867:ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[6892:20824:1009/142756.610:ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[6892:26968:1009/142757.078:ERROR:platform_sensor_reader_win.cc(242)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

Poderiam me clarear sobre o que são exatamente esses erros ?

## EDIT

Código que eu executo para gerar o erro:

```
python webmatic_interactive.py --ou [ambiente de login] --login [chave de login] --partner [parceiro] --password [senha] --token [token de segurança] < [arquivo de onde são extraídos os dados ] > \\[caminho do servidor]\[ relatório do parceiro ]_2018-10-09_2052.txt
```

Codigo do webmatic_interactive.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import webmatic
import argparse
import sys
import proposal
import datetime

def get_context_webdrive():
return getattr(g, '_webdriver', None)

def set_context_webdrive(webdriver):
temp_driver = getattr(g, '_webdriver', None)
if temp_driver is not None:
    temp_driver.close()
g._webdriver =  webdriver   



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--login", help="user login", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--password", help="user password", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--partner", help="partner code", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--token", help="token code", type=str)

parser.add_argument("--ou", help="organization unit", type=str)
parser.add_argument('pns', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)


args = parser.parse_args()
proposalDetails = args.pns.readlines()

proposal_logs = []


password = args.password


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/python/selenium/chromedriver.exe")
url = "[retirado por motivo de segurança]"

try:

for p in proposalDetails:
    prop = p.split(";")
    stripped_pi = prop[1].strip() 
    stripped_pn = prop[0].strip() 
    success, message, status = webmatic.run(args.ou, stripped_pn, args.login, args.partner, password, args.token, driver)
    print(str(success) + ": " + message)
    print("-------------")

    approval_status = "APROVADO" if success else "FALHA"

    # Pegando a última mensagem depois dos ":" caso não seja uma exception.
    log_message = (message) if ("Error" in message) else message.split(":")[-1]
    log_message = log_message.strip()
    
    proposalMessage = ""
    
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    if (approval_status == "APROVADO" or status == "ANÁLISE PROMOTORA" or status == "FORMALIZA PORTABILIDADE" or status == "AGUARDANDO PORTABILIDADE"): 
        proposalMessage = proposal.ApprovePrius(stripped_pi,stripped_pn,args.ou,url)        
    else:
        proposalMessage = "Não aprovado no Promoter"
    
    proposal_log = "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7}".format(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), args.ou, args.partner, status, stripped_pn, approval_status, log_message, proposalMessage)
    proposal_logs.append(proposal_log)
    
finally:
if not driver is None and not driver.session_id is None:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Já que você não consegue disponibilizar o código, faça um [**MCVE**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e coloque na sua pergunta.

Comment: Sim vou estar editando para que caiba algumas coisas a mais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem eu consegui resolver utilizando uma sugestão encontrada no forum do github sobre o selenium que é dar downgrade no chromedriver para a v2.33  e no chrome para v60-61 que são as suportadas no chromedriver... Pelo que entendi o chromedriver parou de implementar algumas funções process_metrics.cc e o platform_sensor_reader_win.cc agora elas são chamadas de outra forma dentro do código, não descobri como... Mas se quiserem podem dar uma olhada no link a seguir https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5189 (Ta em ingles) tem bastante coisa que o pessoal reparou e "fixou" de forma simples

Comment: qual chrome você estava usando?

Comment: v69.0.3497.100 (x64)

Answer (score 1):

O erro é causado por essa linha de código:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/device/generic_sensor/platform_sensor_reader_win.cc#242

Ele ocorre quando a página tenta ler um sensor, que não está implementado no chrome para windows.

Os sensores implementados são: sensor de luz ambiente, acelerômetro, giroscópio, medidor magnético, medidor de orientação.

Se a página tentar usar algum outro sensor que não funciona no windows, por exemplo, medidor de temperatura, medidor de humidade do ar, etc... qualquer coisa, este erro irá aparecer.

Finalmente, **os erros apontados não parece estar relacionado com o problema do programa "não executar de forma correta"**. Caso continue com problemas, sugiro abrir outra pergunta.